# Request failing when trying to pass in parameters in redux-saga for an api call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

The problem is that I am trying to pass in parameters for a api request using redux-saga, but I am getting this error in the browser console: `GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/[object%20Object] 404`. I have already performed console.log(data) in the try block of handleGetPost function, and I getting an object as a response, hence that works just fine. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here.

**Edit**
according to @Daniel Duong, console.log(id) prints out an object that gets passed again into the saga. So how can I pass in a parameter to url, then retrieve the data and store the data inside the state (or store) using redux-saga?

Here is the code:

**FetchPost.js**

```
  const idRef = useRef(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(getPost(idRef.current.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type='text' ref={idRef} name='id' />
      <button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**getPost.js**

```
const GET_POST = 'GET_POST';

const initialState = {
  post: '',
};

const getPost = (id) => ({
  type: GET_POST,
  id,
});

const fetchPostReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POST:
      return { ...state, post: action.id };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export { getPost, GET_POST };
export default fetchPostReducer;
```

**sagas.js**

```
export function requestGetPost(id) {
  return axios.request({
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`,
  });
}

function* handleGetPost(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetPost, action.id);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(getPost(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_POST, handleGetPost);
}
```

Comment: Can you print `action.id` to check what it is?

Comment: Yes, console log(action.id) prints out the value entered in the input tag, and then prints out the object retrieved after the api call. The problem is that that action.id get re-passed into the saga, which is something I'm  trying to stop.

Comment: The 404 is because you have a bad url. You can't convert an object into a string when you put id in the template literal. It's an object.

Comment: So any idea on how to pass a value to url (in my case I'm trying to pass an id value), then storing the retrieved data from the api call inside the state (or store) using redux-saga?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that requestGetPost is returning a promise.
Since axios.request return type is a promise.

```
const responsePromise = yield call(requestGetPost, action.id);
const response = yield responsePromise;
```

I hope this answers your question

Comment: No sorry, that did not seem to work as I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @FST I think what may be happening is that idRef.current.value is returning undefined

Comment: No that did not work either, Here is a link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cherry-mzmhz maybe i'm making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @FST When I console.log(id); I get an object with id, userId, title and body. You are appending that to the url as a string

Comment: Yes, you are right there, but you also tend to get the id value that was entered in the input tag before you get the object. The problem is that how would you store the object that you receive as id after the initial api call, and not pass it in again to the saga?